# .HTacess on PHP Website on WIndows Server2008

Tags: iis-7, .htaccess, php5, web.config

I have a PHP5 website on Windows Server 2008. I want to access .htaccess file. How can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are running Apache you will not be able to use `.htaccess` files for your configuration. Your have two options:

1. Install Apache and set the `AllowOverride All` directive as specified in the [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/core.html#allowoverride).
2. If you decide to use IIS instead of Apache, you will need to use `Web.config` instead of `.htaccess` files to change configuration options. See [this page](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/) for a tutorial on converting `.htaccess` to `Web.config` files.